# Utility to know what classes are loaded by classloader in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have a web application that has some jars under plugins directory

> **Eg: tomcat/webapps/sampleApp/WEB-INF/plugins**

My Tomcat server is throwing `ClassNotFoundException` for those classes. Please let me know how to let tomcat know to load those classes.

Also is there any tool that shows the list of classes loaded by the class loader of tomcat server in Linux machine.